# AxiosError: Network Error with NodeJs and ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

The app is made on React and connects with the backend on another localhost port.

So far it can fetch data and it works when I entry new data using Axios.post http method.

The issue I am having is that every time I submit a new entry with a POST request, Axios gives me this error even though the data does submit and updates:

[image]

I have tested the endpoint with postman and it returns what I want, just a response that says:  `res.json({ msg: 'success, trying to fix Pending HTTP Axios err' })``

I copy below some of my code.
The react component:

```
const AddToList = async (e) => {

    //define axios headers
    const headers = {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    const newEntry = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/addToList", { event: 'random test', finished: true }, { headers })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.response)
        })

}


export const Add = () => {

    const [items, setItems] = useState([])

    return (
        <div>
            <form action="/" >
                <input type="text" />
                <button type="submit" onClick={AddToList} > Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

My controller which handles the request:

```
addToList: async (req, res) => {

        let db = {}

        const data = await fsPromises.readFile('./Database/data.json').catch((err) => console.log('failed to read file ', err))

        const dbResult = await JSON.parse(data.toString())


        const newUser = {
            id: parseInt(dbResult.length) + 1,
            event: req.body.event,
            finished: req.body.finished,
        }

        var newList = await dbResult.push(newUser)

      
        var dataStringify = await JSON.stringify(dbResult)

        fs.writeFile('./Database/data.json', dataStringify, err => {
            if (err) throw err
            console.log("new data added")
        })

        res.json({ msg: 'success, trying to fix Pending HTTP Axios err' })
    }
```

The server route:

```
router.post('/addToList', indexController.addToList)
```

The server index in case I may be missing some import

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require("cors")


app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))


app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}))


var indexRouter = require('./routes/routes')

app.use("/", indexRouter)


app.listen('3001', (req, res) => {
    console.log('backEnd running port 3001')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

the form action is submitting a post request via an HTML form to the root of your server '/', and you are also sending a post request via axios to what looks like the correct URL. You can remove the form and and prevent it from doing that. So it would look something like this

```
  <div>
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="submit" onClick={AddToList}>Add</button>
  </div>
```

You could also keep the form if you want, but you would need to prevent the default submission behavior.

```
const AddToList = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // rest of your code...
}

return (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={addToList}>
      <input type="text" />
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I removed the form action but nothing changed, the error remains, although nice catch.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it a bit more clear let me know if that changes anything

Comment: Thanks, but still the error persists. Could it be something with the axios response?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, can you show the contents of the logged error from your browser?

Comment: I get no errors on the browser. Just the one that that I shared:

Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
Network Error
AxiosError: Network Error
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41592:14)

Nothing else in the console or the browser.

Comment: SOLVED. useEffect was causing repeated XMLHTTP requests which was causing the app to malfunction. Saw it once I changed browser.